# Converting JSON to a Javascript array using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following part of a JSON file. I need to convert to a Javascript array using pure Javascript. Specifically, I need to have an array 
`userid`, `movieid`, `rating`, `timestamp` only for `rating` greater than `4.0`.

```
[{
    "rating": 3.0,
    "ratingsPK": {
        "movieId": 2017,
        "userId": 610
    },
    "timestamp": 913815387
}, {
    "rating": 5.0,
    "ratingsPK": {
        "movieId": 2017,
        "userId": 654
    },
    "timestamp": 959098930
}, {
    "rating": 4.0,
    "ratingsPK": {
        "movieId": 2017,
        "userId": 856
    },
    "timestamp": 1059863336
}, {
    "rating": 2.0,
    "ratingsPK": {
        "movieId": 2017,
        "userId": 903
    },
    "timestamp": 903628492
}, {
    "rating": 3.5,
    "ratingsPK": {
        "movieId": 2017,
        "userId": 1185
    },
    "timestamp": 1100560205
}]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well, and what you have tried.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse, Array.forEach and push it to Array`. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) File using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and that will return as string and imagine you got the file data in variable. `jsonFile`

Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) like below.

```
var rating = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
```

Below is the Working Example.

```js
    var rating = [
      {"rating":3.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":610},"timestamp":913815387},
      {"rating":5.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":654},"timestamp":959098930},
      {"rating":4.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":856},"timestamp":1059863336},
      {"rating":2.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":903},"timestamp":903628492},
      {"rating":3.5,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":1185},"timestamp":1100560205}
];
    
    var bestRated = [];
    
    rating.forEach(function (item) {
      if(item.rating > 4) {
        bestRated.push({
          userid: item.ratingsPK.userId,
          movieid: item.ratingsPK.movieId,
          rating: item.rating,
          timestamp: item.timestamp
        });
      }
    });
    
    console.log('bestRated: ', bestRated);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert a JSON string to a JavaScript object. Then use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with appropriate predicate to get exactly what you need (in your case, `timestamp` greater than 4).

Answer (score 1):

Simple "*one-line*" solution using `JSON.parse()` and `Array.prototype.filter()` functions:

```js
var json_data = '[{"rating":3.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":610},"timestamp":913815387},{"rating":5.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":654},"timestamp":959098930},{"rating":4.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":856},"timestamp":1059863336},{"rating":2.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":903},"timestamp":903628492},{"rating":3.5,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":1185},"timestamp":1100560205}]';
    
var arr = JSON.parse(json_data).filter(function(o){ return o.rating >= 4; });
console.log(arr);
```

The same but in *EcmaScript6* manner(using *arrow function*):

```js
var json_data = '[{"rating":3.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":610},"timestamp":913815387},{"rating":5.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":654},"timestamp":959098930},{"rating":4.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":856},"timestamp":1059863336},{"rating":2.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":903},"timestamp":903628492},{"rating":3.5,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":1185},"timestamp":1100560205}]';
        
var arr = JSON.parse(json_data).filter((o) => o.rating >= 4 );
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

After converting to an object and filtering for rating, you could get an array with taking only the parts of the object, you need.

```js
var data = '[{"rating":3.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":610},"timestamp":913815387},{"rating":5.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":654},"timestamp":959098930},{"rating":4.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":856},"timestamp":1059863336},{"rating":2.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":903},"timestamp":903628492},{"rating":3.5,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":1185},"timestamp":1100560205}]',
    result = JSON.parse(data).filter(function (a) {
        return a.rating > 4;
    }).map(function (a) {
        return [a.ratingsPK.userId, a.ratingsPK.movieId, a.rating, a.timestamp];
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse() can be used to convert JSON to JS object. Below is a exmaple to suit your need.

```
var data='[{"rating":1.0,"ratingsABC":{"movieId":2017,"userId":123},"timestamp":913815387},{"rating":1.0,"ratingsABC":{"movieId":2017,"userId":123},"timestamp":913815387},{"rating":1.0,"ratingsABC":{"movieId":2017,"userId":123},"timestamp":913815387}]';
var sortedData= JSON.parse(data).filter((a) => a.rating >= 4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is without using any fancy API:

```
var jsonArr = [
    {"rating":3.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":610},"timestamp":913815387},
    {"rating":5.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":654},"timestamp":959098930},
    {"rating":4.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":856},"timestamp":1059863336},
    {"rating":2.0,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":903},"timestamp":903628492},
    {"rating":3.5,"ratingsPK":{"movieId":2017,"userId":1185},"timestamp":1100560205}];

var arr = [];

for(var x in jsonArr){
    if(jsonArr[x]['rating'] > 4.0 ){
        arr.push(jsonArr[x]['ratingsPK']['userId']);
        arr.push(jsonArr[x]['ratingsPK']['movieId']);
        arr.push(jsonArr[x]['rating']);
        arr.push(jsonArr[x]['timestamp']);
    }
}
console.log(arr);
```